# Python Print Function Returns None Rather Than Email String

Tags: function, printing, scope, imap

I am attempting to use the imap library to extract text from the latest email in my inbox and then delete the email afterwards. I would like to print the string of the email message returned from the checkemail function; however, the string printed is None.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Solved by listing raw_email as a global variable within the checkemail() function and assigning raw email an empty string before the defined function.

```
import imaplib
import email
import mimetypes
from email import header


def decodeHeader( headerMsg ):
    L = header.decode_header(headerMsg)
    s = ''
    for s1, chset in L:
        if(type(s1) == bytes):
            s += s1.decode(chset) if chset else s1.decode()
        else:
            s += s1
    return s



host = 'imap.gmail.com'
userid = 'emailname@gmail.com'
passwd = 'xxxxxx'

imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host, 993)
imap.login(userid, passwd)

def checkemail():
    global raw_email
    raw_email = ""
    imap.select('INBOX') #or use INBOX
    status, email_ids = imap.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')

    for num in email_ids[0].split():
        type1, data = imap.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        raw_email = data[0][1]
        email_msg = email.message_from_bytes(raw_email)

        type1, data = imap.fetch(num, '(UID BODY[TEXT])')
        raw_email = data[0][1]

        imap.store(num, '+FLAGS', '(\Deleted)')
        imap.expunge()
        imap.close()
        return raw_email

checkemail()
print(checkemail())
```

Comment: write your print statement in for loop and check whether it is going in loop or not, secondly you are calling `checkemail` function twice you should either use `mail = checkemail()` and then `print(mail)` or just use `print(checkemail())`

Comment: are you even able to login? you didn't mentioned port while connecting to imap host

Comment: @Gahan Thanks for the response. When printing raw_input within the function, it is printing the email correctly. Instantiating the class as mail and printing mail still prints None.

Comment: @Gahan Yes, I am able to login as well. I changed the port to 993 just now

Comment: which ide you are using I have run the same code and it's working with minor changes, such as port, allowing permission from google. for more you can write raw_email outside the loop too with if condition that `if raw_email == "":return "no email"`

Comment: @Gahan I am using PyCharm. I have tried     `if raw_email != None:   return raw_email`

Comment: Apologies, I have another python file with the following that prints None:                      `from emails import checkemail                  import time                        while True:
        try:
            print(checkemail())
            time.sleep(5)
            if "computational finance" in checkemail():
                print('hello')
            if "engineering" in checkemail():
                print('hello')
        except TypeError:

            continue`

Comment: If there are no emails matching the criteria UNSEEN, you won't return anything.